WebRtc simple peer
Good morning
I have a problem with simple peer Webrtc
I have finished establishing the connection between the two and I want to display the screen of the participant in the meeting and I can't, it's been 2 days that I've been working on this side.. On the other hand the connection is well established between 2.
so I want to display the participant's exchange at the initiator because it is a streaming
please can someone help me
1 - Code Initiat create offers
async startStream() {
 try {

      // Obtenir les autorisations pour utiliser la caméra et le microphone
      const stream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ video: true, audio: true });

      // Assurez-vous que cette ligne est présente si nécessaire
      this.currentStream = stream;

      // Afficher le lien et activer la conférence
      this.isVisibleLink = true;
      this.isConferenceActive = true;
      this.isLinkSendActive = false;

      // Créer une connexion Peer
      const peerConnection = new RTCPeerConnection({ iceServers: [{ urls: 'stun:stun.l.google.com:19302' }] });

      this.peerConnection = peerConnection;

      // Ajouter les pistes de flux multimédia à la connexion Peer
      stream.getTracks().forEach(track => peerConnection.addTrack(track, stream));

      const dataChannelOptions = {ordered: true};


      peerConnection.createDataChannel('sendDataChannel .... ', dataChannelOptions);


      peerConnection.ondatachannel = (event) => {
          const dataChannel = event.channel;

          dataChannel.onopen = () => {
              console.log('----------- open data-------------');
          };

          dataChannel.onmessage = (event) => {
              const message = event.data;
               console.log('----------- open message -------------');
          };

          dataChannel.onclose = () => {
              console.log('----------- close message -------------' );
          };
      };

      // Gérer les événements de la connexion Peer
      peerConnection.onicecandidate = event => {
          if (event.candidate) {
              console.log(event.candidate);
          }
      };

      const offerOptions = {
          offerToReceiveAudio: 1,
          offerToReceiveVideo: 1
      };

      // Créer une offre SDP
      const offerCreate = await peerConnection.createOffer(offerOptions);
    

      // Définir l'offre locale comme la description de session de la connexion Peer
      await peerConnection.setLocalDescription(offerCreate);
  
      // Stocker l'offre SDP dans votre modèle de données si nécessaire

      this.meetingData.typeOffer = "offer";

      this.meetingData.sdpOffer = peerConnection.localDescription.sdp ;

      this.userBeginOffer = peerConnection.localDescription.sdp ;

      // Créer une réunion ou effectuer d'autres actions nécessaires
      await this.createMeeting();


      axios.post('/uvl/broadcast/sdp-offer', {
            sdpOffer: peerConnection.localDescription.sdp,
            streamId: this.streamLink,
      });

     // Stocker la connexion
     //this.peerConnections.push(peerConnection);

      // Retourner la connexion Peer si nécessaire
      return peerConnection;
  } catch (error) {
      console.error("Erreur lors de la création de la connexion Peer:", error);
  }  
},

2 - Code participant open offer and send answser
async createAnswerPeer(sdpOffer) {
      
  const cleanedSDP = sdpOffer + '\n'
      .split('\n')           // Diviser la chaîne en lignes
      .map(l => l.trim())    // Supprimer les espaces vides autour de chaque ligne
      .join('\r\n');   

    const configuration = { iceServers: [{ urls: 'stun:stun.l.google.com:19302' }] };
   
    const peerConnection = new RTCPeerConnection(configuration);

     const stream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ video: true, audio: true });

     stream.getTracks().forEach(track => peerConnection.addTrack(track, stream));

     this.currentStream = stream;

    // Add Transceivers for receiving video and audio
    peerConnection.addTransceiver('video', { direction: 'recvonly' });
    peerConnection.addTransceiver('audio', { direction: 'recvonly' });

    peerConnection.onicecandidate = event => {

      if (event.candidate) {
        console.log('-------- candidate vents sends-------');
        console.log(event.candidate);
       
      }

    };

    peerConnection.ontrack = event => {
    // Afficher la vidéo du participant
      if (event.track.kind === 'video') {
           // Créer un élément vidéo et y attacher la piste 
           const participantVideo = document.createElement('video');
            participantVideo.autoplay = true;
            participantVideo.srcObject = new MediaStream([event.track]);
            // Ajouter l'élément vidéo à l'élément parent du ref partnerVideo
            this.$refs.partnervideo.appendChild(participantVideo);
            this.$refs.partnervideo.srcObject = stream;

      }
    };


    // Set the remote description (SDP offer)
    await peerConnection.setRemoteDescription({ type: 'offer', sdp: cleanedSDP });

    // Create SDP answer
    const sessionDescription = await peerConnection.createAnswer();
    
    if (!sessionDescription.sdp) {
        console.error("Error: Answer does not contain SDP.");
        return;
      }

    peerConnection.onnegotiationneeded = async () => {
        try {
            console.log('-------- Negotiation needed --------');
            // const sessionDescription = await peerConnection.createAnswer();
            // await peerConnection.setLocalDescription(sessionDescription);
            // await this.sendSDPAnswer(sessionDescription.sdp);
        } catch (error) {
            console.error('Error creating answer:', error);
        }
    };

    const answerSDP = sessionDescription.sdp;
   

    await peerConnection.setLocalDescription(sessionDescription);

     await this.sendSDPAnswer(answerSDP);

      // Cleanup the peer connection when done
      peerConnection.oniceconnectionstatechange = () => {
        if (peerConnection.iceConnectionState === 'disconnected') {
          this.cleanupPeer(peerConnection);
        }
    };
},

3 - Initiator received answer Participant
async  handleParticipantResponse(sdpAnswer) {
  const cleanedSDP = sdpAnswer + '\n'
              .split('\n')           // Diviser la chaîne en lignes
              .map(l => l.trim())    // Supprimer les espaces vides autour de chaque ligne
              .join('\r\n'); 


  const peerConnection = this.peerConnection;

   const stream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ video: true, audio: true });

   stream.getTracks().forEach(track => peerConnection.addTrack(track, stream));


  if (peerConnection.signalingState === 'have-local-offer') {
          console.log('------------ connection est etablie pour le send---------------');
          await peerConnection.setRemoteDescription({ type: 'answer', sdp: cleanedSDP });
      } else {
          console.error('Cannot set remote description in state:');
      } 

  
    peerConnection.onconnectionstatechange = () => {
        if (peerConnection.connectionState === 'connected') {
              console.log('------------ connection est etablie pour la connexetion---------------');
            // La connexion est établie, vous pouvez maintenant appeler setRemoteDescription()
            peerConnection.setRemoteDescription({ type: 'answer', sdp: sdpAnswer });
        }
  };
  

  // Envoi de la réponse SDP au participant 


  peerConnection.onnegotiationneeded = async () => {
    try {
      console.log('---------- conection etablie entre 2 -----------');
       
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error creating answer:', error);
    }
   };


// Add Transceivers for receiving video and audio
peerConnection.addTransceiver('video', { direction: 'recvonly' });
peerConnection.addTransceiver('audio', { direction: 'recvonly' });

peerConnection.ontrack = event => {

  console.log('---------- flux videos---------------');

      if (event.track.kind === 'video') {
        console.log('---------- videos flux-------------');
        const participantVideo = document.createElement('video');
        participantVideo.autoplay = true;
        participantVideo.srcObject = new MediaStream([event.track]);
        this.$refs.participantVideos.appendChild(participantVideo);
      }
 };

  // Gestion des candidats ICE
peerConnection.onicecandidate = event => {
      // Envoyer le candidat ICE au participant
      console.log('---------- send channel users--------');
      if (event.candidate) {
              console.log(event.candidate);
      }
  };

    this.peerConnections.push(peerConnection);
  // Gestion de l'événement ontrack pour afficher le flux vidéo du participant


},


Try first setting up your local description with:
await peerConnection.setRemoteDescription(...),
and then proceed to attach any listeners and execute any other instructions.
